# Передача идентификатора товара при переходе между активностями

Tags: android

Друзья!

Есть приложение android с каталогом товаров, который реализован с помощью ViewPager, в каждой категории (вкладке TabLayout) содержащего список товаров (CardView).

Список товаров формируется (RecyclerView), разделенных по категориям. Каждый товар имеет свой идентификатор в виде номера (itemid)

Информация о товарах заполняется адаптером (RecyclerView.Adapter)

Я установил слушатель, отслеживающий клик по карточке. По клику осуществляется переход на другую активность (ItemActivity), в которой, предполагается открывать товар.

Однако я не могу сообразить как мне передать в другую активность (ItemActivity) идентификатор товара (itemid), что бы уже по нему уже заполнять данные.

Может есть возможность к каждой карточке привязать метаданные, которые заполнить идентификаторами? Погуглил - ничего не нашел по этому вопросу.

Поделитесь, пожалуйста, опытом.

Спасибо.

Comment: Передавать данные надо через `Intent#putExtra(String key, Int data)` - доставать аналогично. Если у вас в слушаетеле нажатий ID нет - добавьте его

Comment: В методе интерфейса ввел параметр itemId и передал его при клике по карточке в самом адаптере. Далее уже внутри фрагмента через Intent#putExtra передал в целевую активность нужный идентификатор. Юрий, спасибо). Все заработало.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В методе интерфейса ввел параметр itemId и передал его при клике по карточке в самом адаптере. Далее уже внутри фрагмента через Intent#putExtra передал в целевую активность нужный идентификатор.